# PostgreSQL Joining 2 Queries for PHP loop

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, join

First post, thanks in advance! I'm sorry to have to ask but I've been having tons of trouble getting into SQL joins with PostgreSQL. I'm working on pulling information from 2 tables and then using PHP to fill a table in. I have looked all over the forums and I'm still having trouble. These are the 2 queries I'm trying to join together.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE g_date BETWEEN current_date AND current_date + 7;"; 
$result = pg_query($query);
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM nvo1 WHERE g_date BETWEEN current_date AND current_date + 7;";
$result2 = pg_query($query2);
```

I'm using some fields from the first query in a PHP loop to fill out the first half of the table and some from the second to fill out the last half. Thanks again for any help and I hope everyone is having a great day.

Comment: do you want to combine the result of both the queries ? If yes, then look up for `UNION`

Comment: It's giving an error stating that they have to have the same number of columns to do the UNION schedule has more columns than nvo1.

Comment: @Prdp

I tried adding null columns to make them have the same number of columns but that didn't work either.

The closest I've come to getting it to work properly is this:

`code` select * from nvo1 inner join schedule on (nvo1.g_date = schedule.g_date) where nvo1.g_date BETWEEN current_date -7 AND current_date; `code`

It pulls the first row properly, because there is only 1 entry on that day. The others pull the same fields 7 times in a row on the schedule table. And on the nvo1 table it loops through the same ones.

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @Prdp

This pulls similar results
`select * from nvo1 inner join schedule USING (g_date) where nvo1.g_date BETWEEN current_date -7 AND current_date;`